# Hit problem and $\left( \mathbb{F}_2 \otimes_{A} P_6 \right)_{10}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

I try to determine the $\left(\mathbb{F}_2 \otimes_{A} P_6 \right)_{10}$ as a $\mathbb{F}_2$- vector space, in which $P_6$ is polynomial algebra $\mathbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_6]$ and $A$ is Steenrod algebra.

Denote the monomial $x_1^a x_2^b x_3^c x_4^d x_5^e x_6^f$ by $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$.

I consider the monomial $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ in 6 cases, for example, case 1: the monomial depends only on one variable.

I do not know what is the genarator of $\left(\mathbb{F}_2 \otimes_{A} P_6 \right)_{10}$ and its dimension. So, I just consider case by case except any criterion for hit problem.

My question is: What is the generator of $\left(\mathbb{F}_2 \otimes_{A} P_6 \right)_{10}$ and its dimension?

Can you help me to give some ideas for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $P_6$ and $A$-module?

Comment: Yes. Let $Sq^j$ be a square operation in Steenrod algebra. We have $$Sq^j(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x, \ \ \ \text{if $j=0$,}\\ 
x^2, \ \ \ \text{if $j=1$,}\\ 
0. \ \ \ \text{otherwise.}
\end{matrix}\right.$$ And it satisfies the Cartan fomular $$Sq^{n}(fg)=\sum_{i=0}^nSq^i(f)Sq^{n-i}(g).$$

Comment: You mean that for $x= x_1,\dots, x_6$? What's the degree of the $x_i$?

Comment: I am sorry. The monomial $x_1^a\dots x_6^f$ with $10=a+ \dots f$. In above fomular, $x$ means $x_i$.

Comment: I still don't get the degrees

Comment: $P_6$ means the cohomology of a 6-fold product of $\mathbf{R}P^\infty$ with itself. Thus it's a polynomial ring on 6 generators, each in degree 1.

Comment: I may be horribly mistaken, but if you're killing the action of the Steenrod algebra, you obtain a quotient of the exterior algebra on the same generators, which is trivial above dimension 6, so the answer would be 0.

Comment: Fernando: If $P_1=\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, then $\mathbb{F}_2 \otimes_A P_1$ is spanned by the elements $x^{2^n-1}$. So it's more complicated than that.

Comment: I see, $x^2=0$ but higher powers need not be $0$ since you're killing a sub-$A$-bmodule of $P_1$, not an ideal, that's my mistake.